# PHP LI count divisions

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a loop that displays `<li>`'s and I need to add a class to the 1st and then every six `<li>`'s

Example:

```
while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    <li (if mod of 6 add class="something")>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li class="something">Six</li>
    <li>Seven</li>

}
...
```

Comment: Yes, it's reading the records from the database

Comment: `IF($i % 6 == 0) add the class`

Comment: use modulus if($a % $b == 6) $class='whatever';

Comment: You could have saved much more time if you had tried on your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite easy using the [**modulus `%`**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) operator:

```
$counter = 0;
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) {
    $isSixthsLi = (bool) (($counter++) % 6 == 0); 
    echo $isSixthsLi ? '<li class="something">' : '<li>';
    echo htmlentities($r['content']);
    echo '</li>';
}
```

The `($counter++) % 6` expression means *the remainder of $counter divided by 6, then increment $counter*. If the remainder is zero (and this is true for 0, 6, 12, ...), then you print the `<li>` with a class name, else you did not.

Comment: The parenthesis around `$count++` is superfluous. And around the comparison as well. And yeah oh, a single `!` would have made it.

Comment: @hakre I know, but I always write more parenthesis than necessary, especially when I use and/or on conditions. More legible, I get it immediately. Idem with $counter++. About the == 0, the OP (seems) not to know modulus at all, so better write meaningful expression, don't you think? :)

Comment: I prefer how it was before. For me, it's clearer for newbies. You tell me about too much verbosity, then you add more? :) Btw, thank you for your remarks.

Comment: Yours is more complex because you mix the responsibility to tell whether it's that row or not with the output. Because it's more complex, it's less easy to understand for newbies (and oldies).

Answer (score 1):

i think this list is coming dynamically then you can use

```
<?php 
 $i=0;
 foreach ($in as $v){  
        $i++;
        $class = (!$i%6) ? "something : "";  ?>
        <li class="<?=$class?>"><?=$v?></li>   

<?php } ?>
```

**Note :** i have use shorthand tag `<?=` , you can use `<?php echo` instead